# How to access the current date of the day after opening the app?

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access the current date of the day after opening the app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6487797/how-to-access-the-current-date-of-the-day-after-opening-the-app)

I'm working on a project with calenders that are going to cater to the visually impaired. How can I make it so that when my calender app starts, it shows the current date instead of the normal grid view?

Answer (score 0):

```
Time t = new Time();
t.setToNow();
```

Comment: thanks for that. but where do i insert this part of the code to? java/manifest/ or....?